# How do I trim all whitespace in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, whitespace

In my example I want to individually markup letters in the word "word"

```
%span.word
  %span.w W
  %span.o O
  %span.r R
  %span.d D
```

As it is, this produces html like

```
<span class="word">
  <span class="w">W</span>
  <span class="o">O</span>
  <span class="r">R</span>
  <span class="d">D</span>
</span>
```

As you'd expect this displays as

> W O R D

But I want it to display as

> WORD

How can tell haml to remove all whitespace within the `%span.word` block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
%span.word
  %span.w> W
  %span.o> O
  %span.r> R
  %span.d> D
```

`>` (for whitespaces around a tag) and `<` (for whitespaces inside a tag) are used for whitespace removal.

Answer (score 1):

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#remove_whitespace-instance_method

HAML allows you set a remove_whitespace option which will remove whitespace from all tags, if you don't want to litter your templates with < and > everywhere.